# In Python, why is contains() a hidden method on str object?

Tags: python

Often I check if a substring is present in a string. In Python I could do that either using the `__contains__()` method or using the `in` operator as shown below:

Pattern 1:

```
string1 = r'c:\users\username\documents\code\crime_data.csv'
print(string1.__contains__('username'))
```

Pattern 2:

```
print('username' in string1)
```

Both work well for me, but I would like to know why is `__contains__` hidden method and if pattern 2 preferred over 1, if so why? Other programming languages like C# do have a `String.contains()` method in their standard library.

Comment: Why would you want to write `x.contains(y)` instead of `y in x`?  The reason `__contains__` is a magic method is the same as the reason you write `x + y` and not `x.__add__(y)`, namely that, where an infix operator is available, it is generally more readable than a function call.

Comment: When you call `something in something2` Python looks for a magic `__contains__` method in `something2` object and calls it (and for some builtins the interpreter can even optimize away such call). The `in` is just a syntactic sugar to keep the code more readable. As to why is it a separate method - so that you can create your own types that can be compared with other types.

Comment: Furthering what BrenBarn said, the `in` operator is also faster than a method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator can be overloaded by redefining the method `__contains__`.
This is no different from e.g. `__add__` (`+`), `__mul__` (`*`), etc. So the point is not to hide the method, but to make it fit the convention for 'magic methods', used to overload operators.